# Defect in the square-root symbol in Stack Exchange

Tags: symbols, sqrt

`\sqrt{aaa}` in Math Stack Exchange yields a square-root symbol with a small gap which is unwanted. The picture attached below will show it clearly.[image]

But in overleaf `\sqrt{aaa}` gives a fine symbol without any such gap. The following picture is a screenshot from an overleaf document.
[image]

Can we do something to avoid this small gap in the square-root symbol in MSE?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a specific issue of MathJax that can't be solved on the TeX side. Use a phantom `\sqrt{aaa\vphantom{b}}`.

Comment: Overleaf runs "real" LaTeX, but Math.SE does not; instead, it runs MathJax. MathJax recognizes LaTeX-like syntax, but the underlying engine is not TeX (or pdfTeX). MathJax-related questions are off-topic on TeX.SE.

Comment: @egreg thank you!